# How to have a bottom UIView that always stays in view but a top UIView that changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am currently designing an app where I have a bottom view that has information and is displayed all the time. However, the other half of the screen I want to be able to navigate and change views (hopefully using a navigation controller). Is there anyway I can do this, where the top view has freedom to change and push view controllers like a regular app. But have the bottom UIView stay there updating its information? What is a general design approach I should take?

Comment: What type of information are you wanting to have in the bottom view? A Tab Bar Controller would certainly persist throughout the app, but doesn't exactly display information. Rather, it just gives you the ability to take you to different parts of an app to see that information. Each tab could have a navigation controller.

Comment: @croberth It's a view that contains a button to submit the information in the app to a server, and few labels that change their text based off what the user enters. Therefore, I'm not sure how viable a tab bar would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay , I think there's a simpler solution. You can achieve this using container views. Have a viewController (parent) which manages the static content. Embed a container view in the parenViewController and place a navigationController within the containerView.

Here's an illustration on how to put this together. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView subclass for the bottom view and have each view controller place the bottom view at the bottom of its view.  You might ask:

1. *Isn't that a lot of code?*  Not if you put all the stuff that bottom view does inside the bottom view class.
2. *Isn't it wasteful to have many instances of it?*  Maybe, but think of it as a UIControl. We're happy to have a lot of instances of UIButtons, one for every button in our app.
3. *Isn't it a lot of redundant code to frame up the bottom view and add as a subview in every view controller?*  If there are a lot of view controllers, have them inherit from a new vc subclass called ViewControllerWithBottomView that does the framing and adding on its viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `UIWindow` and give it a high enough `windowLevel` for whatever you need, and then use that window to display your bottom view. This way it also doesn't take part in any view controller animation like the solution suggested by @danh would.